# How to change value inside an array while iterating over it in Rust

Tags: rust

I want to change the value inside the loop like in the comment. It should be simple but I don't see the solution.

```
fn main() {
    let mut grid: [[i32; 10]; 10] = [[5; 10]; 10];
    for (i, row) in grid.iter_mut().enumerate() {
        for (y, col) in row.iter_mut().enumerate() {
            //grid[i][y] = 7;
            print!("{}", col);
        }
        print!("{}","\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `iter_mut` iterator gives you a reference to the element, which you can use to mutate the grid. You usually shouldn't use indices.

```
fn main() {
    let mut grid: [[i32; 10]; 10] = [[5; 10]; 10];
    for row in grid.iter_mut() {
        for cell in row.iter_mut() {
            *cell = 7;
        }
    }

    println!("{:?}", grid)
}
```

[Playground link](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=eea0c4505011230e878a416722eaaee6&version=stable)

Comment: More idiomatically seen as `for row in &mut grid {` and `for cell in &mut row {`.

Comment: ^ nice, this is more convenient