# What is the standard approach in the Rust community to iterate over a struct's field and change another field in the loop?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

This non-working [piece of code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9741b7318555d186c5208df7dba6d3f9) describes my problem:

```rust
use std::sync::mpsc::{Sender, channel};

struct Node {
    counter: usize,
    senders: Vec<Sender<usize>>,
}

impl Node {
    fn inc_counter(&mut self) {
        self.counter += 1;
    }
    fn send(&mut self) {
        for s in self.senders.iter() {
            self.inc_counter();   // <-- If just I put `self.counter += 1` here, the borrow checker is happy
            s.send(self.counter);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let (tx, _) = channel();
    let mut n = Node{
        counter: 0,
        senders: vec![tx],
    };
    n.send();
}
```

I'm trying to borrow `self` mutable when it's already borrowed immutable.
Inlining `inc_counter` body works fine for this simple case, but in general case it makes code harder to read and limits refactoring.

It's a pretty common thing to iterate over something and change internal state, isn't it?

There are a few things that I tried:

1. Organize code differently e.g. use one struct for immutable data and one for keeping own state and pass everything as parameters to method.
2. Apply interior mutability and wrap `counter` in `Cell`.
3. Replace `for s in self.senders.iter()` with `for i in 0..self.senders.len()` and get a reference to a particular sender inside the loop.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Why does refactoring by extracting a method trigger a borrow checker error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57017747/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: See also [Efficiently mutate a vector while also iterating over the same vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49143770/155423); [Mutating one field while iterating over another immutable field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35936995/155423); [How can you iterate and change the values in a mutable array in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56963011/155423);

Comment: [How to change value inside an array while iterating over it in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48492204/155423); [How to mutate another item in a vector, but not the vector itself, while iterating over the vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35823029/155423)